# Tools namespace attribute for showing layout in ViewPager in design time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tools-namespace

The [tools namespace](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) allows for showing view properties in layout designer.

For example using `tools:listItem="@layout/{custom_layout}` it is possible to show list with custom row layout in Android Studio designer.

Question is:

> Is it possible to show layout inside `ViewPager`?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that. **tools:listitem did not work** for ViewPager as you know.

Comment: Also seems that `tools:listitem` does not work for [`ViewPager2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.html).

Answer (score 36):

Nope, there is no such attribute.

**Currently (Mar 2021) there is:**

- tools:context *Intended for: Any root View*
- tools:itemCount *Intended for: RecyclerView*
- tools:layout *Intended for: fragment*
- tools:listitem / tools:listheader / tools:listfooter
  *Intended for: AdapterView (and subclasses like ListView)*
- tools:showIn *Intended for: Any root View in a layout that's referred to by an include*
- tools:menu *Intended for: Any root View*
- tools:minValue / tools:maxValue *Intented for: NumberPicker*
- tools:openDrawer *Intented for DrawerLayout*

For resources

- tools:shrinkMode
- tools:keep
- tools:discard
- tools:locale

Error Handling:

- tools:ignore *Intented for any: Any element*
- tools:targetApi *Intended for: Any element*

General:

- tools: instead of android: *Intended for: View*

[Official Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)

Comment: `tools:parentTag` could probably be added to this list. Intended for: Merge tag

Comment: @Khay no it is not. Reason for downvoting: the question was about showing design-time layout as item of `ViewPager`. `tools:listItem` does not work for that since it is for `AdapterView` subclasses, and `ViewPager` is a direct subclass of `ViewGroup`